# Check and Install a feature using a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to automate below process using .bat file :

**NOTE :**  Below posted code is not proper , they are the tried code by me .

1. First check if the program is installed
2. If not installed write in the cmd host that file is not installed .
3. If not installed install the feature
4. Finally write cmd console host install is successful or failed .

**.bat code :**

```
@echo off
title Check and Install MS Visual C++ Redistributable 2015
echo Checking MS Visual C++ Redistributable 2015 .....

@ECHO OFF 

REM LOG LOCATION 
SET LOGPATH=D:\Tool\InstallC++Log\
IF NOT EXIST %LOGPATH% MD %LOGPATH%

SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0 
REM PowerShellScriptPath=C:\temp\Install_Program_MS_Visual_C++_x86.ps1
SET PowerShellScriptPath=C:\temp\Checking_Program.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%'"; >> %LOGPATH%%INSTALLPATCH%.log

pause
```

**C:\temp\Checking_Program.ps1 code below  :**

```
$tempdir = Get-Location
$tempdir = $tempdir.tostring()
$appToMatch = 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86)'
$msiFile = $tempdir+"\microsoft.interopformsredist.msi"
$msiArgs = "-qb"

function Get-InstalledApps
{
    if ([IntPtr]::Size -eq 4) {
        $regpath = 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
    }
    else {
        $regpath = @(
            'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
            'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
        )
    }
    Get-ItemProperty $regpath | .{process{if($_.DisplayName -and $_.UninstallString) { $_ } }} | Select DisplayName, Publisher, InstallDate, DisplayVersion, UninstallString |Sort DisplayName
}

$result = Get-InstalledApps | where {$_.DisplayName -like $appToMatch}


If ($result -eq $null) {

     Write-Host "Could not find the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86). Installing the Program..." 
      }

  }
```

After this I would like to see command prompt entry that Installing the feature .

**Install .bat code :**

```
@echo off
title Installing MS Visual C++ Redistributable 2015
echo .....

@ECHO OFF 

REM LOG LOCATION 
SET LOGPATH=D:\Tool\InstallC++Log\
IF NOT EXIST %LOGPATH% MD %LOGPATH%

SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0 
REM PowerShellScriptPath=C:\temp\Install_Program_MS_Visual_C++_x86.ps1
SET PowerShellScriptPath=C:\temp\Checking_Program_Install.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%'"; >> %LOGPATH%%INSTALLPATCH%.log

pause
```

**Installing PowerShell code below :**

```
$computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$sourcefile = "C:\temp\C++\vc_redist.x86.exe"


    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {Start-Process 'C:\temp\C++\vc_redist.x86.exe' -ArgumentList /s -Verb runas -Wait   }
```

Once Installed , I should get command prompt message saying that Feature is successfully Installed . Please help .

Comment: Why are you using `-Command " & ps1"` instead of `-File "ps1"` ?

Comment: Is the redistributable installation not clever enough to either not install over itself, or harmlessly overwrite itself if it already exists?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 , I am trying it on my own , checking google . I am not aware of preparing .bat file . I want this .bat file to check the program and install if not exists but I want it to be interactive by opening cmd and executable

Comment: @DBOn If you want it to be interactive, what's the point of creating a script?

Comment: @Compo , I checked the programs and this feature is not installed . But I do have close to 100 Citrix machines where this feature is not installed . So with my minimum knowledge I am trying this code for automation .

Comment: I correct myself , interactive I mean , if program exists end the code , if not check and continue install .

Answer (score 1):

So while checking if it's installed, you had a few pointless comments and declarations:

*Install.cmd*

```
@ECHO off
TITLE Check and Install MS Visual C++ Redistributable 2015

SET LOGPATH=D:\Tool\InstallC++Log
IF NOT EXIST %LOGPATH% MD %LOGPATH%

SET PowerShellScriptPath=C:\Temp\Install.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "%PowerShellScriptPath%" >> %LOGPATH%\Redist.log

PAUSE
```

It's unnecessary to declare a function that is only called once.  I think it's a bad practice to use the current directory as a temp folder; you should use a default or create one.  Ultimately, your examples don't make sense so I tried to make some sense of it:

*Install.ps1*

```
#Requires -Version 3

$TargetApp = 'Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86)'

$RegPath = @('HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*')
If ([Environment]::Is64BitOperatingSystem)
{
    $RegPath += 'HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*'
}

$Result = Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegPath |
  Where-Object { $PSItem.DisplayName -eq $TargetApp -and
                 $PSItem.UninstallString } |
  Select-Object -Property @('DisplayName','Publisher','InstallDate','DisplayVersion','UninstallString')

If ($Null -eq $Result)
{
    Write-Output "Could not find '$TargetApp'. Installing the Program..."
    $Params=@{
        FilePath='C:\Temp\C++\vc_redist.x86.exe'
        ArgumentList='/s'
        Verb='RunAs'
        Wait=$True
    }
    Start-Process @Params
}
```

Comment: Thank you @TheIncorrigible1, will check now .